# How to decorate InputDialog in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, plugins, eclipse-plugin

How do I extend a simple InputDialog in an eclipse plugin to put additional checkboxes, radio buttons, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own dialog box. You do that by using SWT, the Eclipse UI framework. If you are a good Java coder, the best thing you can (IMHO) do is look at the [SWT code snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).

Another option, perhaps better one, is using JFace. It is a framework built on top of SWT. JFace makes it easier to build the UI and it works with SWT without hiding it. You can find many code examples of doing dialog boxes with JFace [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Dialog.htm).

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to nWire. Thanks. I'm glad you like it.